# Error connecting with SSL using IdHttp Indy

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, delphi-5, idhttp

I have a problem in IdHttp using Indy (Delphi).

I try to using IdHttp to post XML in web service SOAP, but dont work. Return "Error connecting with SSL." in IdSSLOpenSSL.Connect@1437 from indy.

My code is simple:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vRequest : TStringStream;
  s : String;
begin
  vRequest  := TStringStream.Create((Memo1.Lines.Text));
  try
    IdHTTP1.Host                       := edHost.Text;
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentLength      := length(Memo1.Lines.Text);
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType        := edContentType.Text;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Text := 'SOAPAction: "removed for safe"'#13#10;
    IdHTTP1.request.CacheControl       := 'no-cache';
    IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptEncoding     := edAccept.Text;
    IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions                := [hoKeepOrigProtocol];
    IdHTTP1.ProtocolVersion            := pv1_1;

    Memo2.Clear;
    try
      s := IdHTTP1.post(Edit1.Text, vRequest);
      Memo2.Lines.Text := s;
    except
      on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
        Label1.Caption     := e.Message;
        MEMO2.LINES.TEXT   := e.Message;
      end;
      on e:Exception do begin
        Label1.Caption     := e.Message;
        MEMO2.LINES.TEXT   := e.Message;
      end;
    end;

    requestHeaders.Lines.Text  := IdHTTP1.Request.RawHeaders.Text;
    responseHeaders.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders.Text;
  finally
    vRequest.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In exe folder contain libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. Any sugestion?

I Used delphi 5, but in delphi 7 is the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `SSLVersions` property of `TIdSSLIOHandlerSockOpenSSL` is set to enable only TLS 1.0 <sup>1</sup>.  But many websites are starting to phase out TLS 1.0 and only accept TLS 1.1+.  So try enabling TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 in the `SSLVersions` property and see if it helps.

<sup>1: there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181) in Indy's issue tracker to also enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 by default.</sup>

---

On a side note, there are some further tweaks you should make to your code:

- do not assign any values to `TIdHTTP`'s `Host` or `ContentLength` properties. They are populated automatically by `TIdHTTP`.
- if you set the `AcceptEncoding` property manually, make sure NOT to include `deflate` or `gzip` unless you have a `Compressor` assigned to `TIdHTTP`, otherwise it will fail to decode a compressed response.  You really should not assign anything to `AcceptEncoding` unless you are prepared to handle custom encodings.  The `Compressor` handles `deflate`/`gzip` and `TIdHTTP` will update `AcceptEncoding` accordingly if a `Compressor` is assigned and ready for use.
- use the `CustomHeaders.Values` property to set individual headers, not the `CustomHeaders.Text` property.
- you do not need to catch `EIdHTTPProtocolException` explicitly, since that exception handler is not doing anything extra that the more generic `Exception` handler is not doing.
- the `RawHeaders` property is a `TStringList` descendant, so it is more efficient to use `Lines.Assign(RawHeaders)` instead of `Lines.Text := RawHeaders.Text`.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vRequest : TStringStream;
  s : String;
begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := edContentType.Text;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['SOAPAction'] := 'removed for safe';
  IdHTTP1.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
  IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol];
  IdHTTP1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;

  Memo2.Clear;
  try
    vRequest := TStringStream.Create(Memo1.Lines.Text);
    try
      s := IdHTTP1.Post(Edit1.Text, vRequest);
    finally
      vRequest.Free;
    end;
    Memo2.Lines.Text := s;
  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      Label1.Caption := e.Message;
      Memo2.Lines.Text := e.Message;
    end;
  end;

  RequestHeaders.Lines.Assign(IdHTTP1.Request.RawHeaders);
  ResponseHeaders.Lines.Assign(IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It turned out the problem was something with the OpenSSl dlls, after updating it it worked just fine. Oddly, and i'm not sure why, after updating the dlls, the SSL Handler is not loading the dll library on the first attempt, but if i try again, the second time onwards works completely normal, to work around that we simply called IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load() on the application initialization. But nonetheless thanks for your side notes, it will be very useful on future implementations to maintain a cleaner code!

Comment: "*the SSL Handler is not loading the dll library on the first attempt, but if i try again, the second time onwards works completely normal*" - what does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function report when OpenSSL fails to load the first time?